# Get Upload Folder and Filename from Browser

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, browser

Is it possible to get the client's directory path for a file that is uploaded to a server?

Comment: For privacy's sake I hope not. Why would you want it?

Answer (score 1):

Most contemporary browser do not show the complete path to a file's origin, but something like `/fakepath/file.ext`.

But it depends on your browser.

Comment: Yep, for the sake of user privacy. I wouldn't want a website to be able to collect information about the location of my files every time I upload something.