# Php Browse a file then get its path

Tags: php, html, file, path

Been stumbling around the net having a difficulty finding a sample of getting a file path of a browsed file. Some of them I read that this function no longer works anymore due to security reasons. Any ideas guys? I badly need a sample. I already tried many times.

This is currently I have:

```
<html>

<body>


<form method="post" action="file.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="radio" name="type" value="moodle" required="required" /> Moodle<br />
<input type="radio" name="type" value="bb" required="required" /> BlackBoard<br />
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />

</form> 

</body>

</html>
```

the file.php

```
<?php


$filetype = $_POST["type"];




echo $filetype;

echo "Upload: " . $_FILES['file']['name'] . "<br />";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

if ($_FILES['file']['error'] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES['file']['name'] . "<br />";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES['file']['type'] . "<br />";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES['file']['size'] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  }


function moodlezip($zipfile){

    echo "<h1>MOODLE</h1>"."<br />";

    $moodle = new Moodle();
    $zip = zip_open($zipfile);
    $ziparc = new ZipArchive;


    if ($zip)
    {
        while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip))
        {

            $file = zip_entry_name($zip_entry);

            //echo "Name: " . $file . "<br />";


            if (strpos($file,'course.xml') !== false) {

                if ($ziparc->open($zipfile) === TRUE) {

                    $coursexml =  new SimpleXMLElement($ziparc->getFromName($file));

                    $moodle->getCourse($coursexml);

                    $ziparc->close();


                } else {
                    echo 'failed';
                }


            }

            else if (strpos($file,'forum.xml') !== false) {

                if ($ziparc->open($zipfile) === TRUE) {

                    $topicxml =  new SimpleXMLElement($ziparc->getFromName($file));

                    $moodle->getTopic($topicxml);

                    $ziparc->close();


                } else {
                    echo 'failed';
                }


            }



            else if (strpos($file,'lesson.xml') !== false) {

                if ($ziparc->open($zipfile) === TRUE) {

                    $lessonxml =  new SimpleXMLElement($ziparc->getFromName($file));

                    $moodle->getLessons($lessonxml);

                    $ziparc->close();


                } else {
                    echo 'failed';
                }


            }



            else if (strpos($file,'quiz.xml') !== false) {

                if ($ziparc->open($zipfile) === TRUE) {

                    $quizxml =  new SimpleXMLElement($ziparc->getFromName($file));

                    $moodle->getQuizzes($quizxml);

                    $ziparc->close();


                } else {
                    echo 'failed';
                }


            }


            else if (strpos($file,'questions.xml') !== false) {

                if ($ziparc->open($zipfile) === TRUE) {

                    $questionsxml =  new SimpleXMLElement($ziparc->getFromName($file));

                    $moodle->getQuestions($questionsxml);

                    $ziparc->close();


                } else {
                    echo 'failed';
                }


            }


        }

        zip_close($zip);
    }

}

require_once 'classes/backup.php';

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");


if (!$connect)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close($connect);


//form upload loop folders input submit, find, bb, scorm
//class admin
?>
```

Comment: I think you need to provide an example of what you are trying to do, it's not very clear.

Comment: What do you mean by a "browsed file"?  Is this file on the *server* or the *client*?  If the file is from the client, you **cannot** get its path.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Upload Folder and Filename from Browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660094/get-upload-folder-and-filename-from-browser) (and [many, many others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fakepath+get+real+path+of+file+on+client))

Comment: Why do you need it "badly" (adding that is not going to make us help you any more than normal)?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to clarify myself. I already updated my question. You see i need the file path to pass it on my functions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to resolve the C:\fakepath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pathinfo() http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: That gets the place the file was uploaded to, not the place that it was uploaded from (which is blocked (as the question admits) for security (and privacy) reasons).

Comment: okay I will to apply it in a form.

Comment: so what ways now can I do this? if the said above is useless

Comment: @mrpotatohead1251: You need to first tell us what *exactly* you are trying to do.

Comment: "When a user sends binary data to your server via the <file> HTML element, you do not have access to the path under which the data resided - you only have the data. " Ref. http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/877811-possible-save-local-system-file-path-php-session.  I can only help you get the data that is available.

Comment: okay like this. the user will upload the backup file of moodle which is in a zip type. then its path to be pass on a function which needs the file path of the zip file

Comment: @mrpotatohead1251:  Sorry for not understanding you.  Are you trying to get the path to a file on the server or on the user's local machine?  If it's the server, see my answer above.  If it's the local machine, it is my understanding that this is not possible.

Comment: sir its in the local machine. So I will just forget about the file path. And go straight with uploading the zip and store it somewhere else. I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the full path of the file for security reasons. The [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html) and [RFC](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2388.html) specifications do **not** mention that the full file-path should be available. You can only get the filename (`document.getElementById("filefield_id").value` for instance returns the name).

The reason is probably that if one had the ability to get/change the file path, one could also go around stealing files from users via hidden fields. The bottomline: it's not possible. Maybe we could be of more help if you tell us what you're *exactly* trying to do.

Comment: i dont need the file name haays

Comment: @mrpotatohead1251 Yes, well you can't get anything other than the filename -- the file path is simply made **unavailable** by the browser. Sorry.

Comment: okay I guess. So what options do I have?. The class I made with its function really need the file to be specific zip file. Can I just upload it somewhere?